# Resetting all vars for d3 force directed graph, javascript, svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm new to d3 and svg and I've put together a force directed graph from various examples.

When I call the d3Graph() function below the first time, it draws correctly (1st image). When I call it a second time, it does not (2nd image). If I refresh the page and call it again it works correctly. I've explicitly nullified all the variables so I can't see why it's not re-drawing correctly - ie I want it to act the same as a page reload so each call is a completely fresh run that re-reads the JSON and draws from scratch.

Any help would be great

**1st call does correct draw:**

[image: d3 directed graph]

**2nd call without refreshing page problem:**

[image]

**d3 code:**

```
function d3Graph() {

var linkDistance = 100;
var colors = d3.scale.category10();
var w = 1000;
var h = 600;

var links= null;
var nodes= null;
var force= null;
var edges= null;
var nodelabels= null;
var edgepaths= null;
var edgelabels= null;
var svg= null;

d3.select("svg").selectAll("*").remove();
$("#svg_container").empty();

svg = d3.select("#svg_container").append("svg").attr({
    "width" : w,
    "height" : h
});

d3.json("/workflows/graph.json?id=1", function(error, dataset) {

    if (error)
        throw error;

    links = [];
    dataset.edges.forEach(function(e) {
        var sourceNode = dataset.nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return n.id === e.source;
        })[0], targetNode = dataset.nodes.filter(function(n) {
        return n.id === e.target;
        })[0];

        links.push({
            id : e.id,
            edge_type : e.edge_type,
            source : sourceNode,
            target : targetNode
        });
    });

    force = d3.layout.force().nodes(dataset.nodes).links(links).size([w, h]).linkDistance([linkDistance]).charge([-2000]).theta(0.1).gravity(0.05).start();

    edges = svg.selectAll("line").data(links).enter().append("line").attr("id", function(d, i) {
        return 'edge' + i
    })

    .attr('marker-end', function(d) {
        if (d.edge_type == 'prerequisite') {
            return 'url(#arrowhead)';
        }
    })
    .attr('stroke', function(d) {
        if (d.edge_type == 'prerequisite') {
            return '#000';
        } else {
            return '#F00';
        }
    })

    nodes = svg.selectAll("circle").data(dataset.nodes).enter().append("circle").attr({
        "r" : 15
    }).style("fill", function(d, i) {
        return colors(i);
    }).call(force.drag).on("click", function(d) {
        $('#workflow_stage_id').val(d.id);
        $('#workflow_stage_name').val(d.name);
    });

    nodelabels = svg.selectAll(".nodelabel").data(dataset.nodes).enter().append("text").attr({
        "x" : function(d) {
            return d.x;
        },
        "y" : function(d) {
            return d.y;
        },
        "class" : "nodelabel",
        "stroke" : "black"
    }).text(function(d) {
        return d.name + ' [ID:' + d.id + ']';
    });

    edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath").data(links).enter().append('path').attr({
        'd' : function(d) {
            return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y
        },
        'class' : 'edgepath',
        'fill-opacity' : 0,
        'stroke-opacity' : 0,
        'fill' : 'blue',
        'stroke' : 'red',
        'id' : function(d, i) {
            return 'edgepath' + i
        }
    })

    edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel").data(links).enter().append('text').on("click", function(d) {
        $('#workflow_stage_edge_id').val(d.id);
    })
    .attr({
        'class' : 'edgelabel',
        'id' : function(d, i) {
            return 'edgelabel' + i
        },
        'dx' : 50,
        'dy' : 0,
        'font-size' : 14,
        'fill' : '#000'
    });

    edgelabels.append('textPath').attr('xlink:href', function(d, i) {
        return '#edgepath' + i
    })
    .text(function(d, i) {
        return 'ID:' + d.id
    });

    svg.append('defs').append('marker').attr({
        'id' : 'arrowhead',
        'viewBox' : '-0 -5 10 10',
        'refX' : 25,
        'refY' : 0,
        'orient' : 'auto',
        'markerWidth' : 10,
        'markerHeight' : 10,
        'xoverflow' : 'visible'
    }).append('svg:path').attr('d', 'M0 ,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5').attr('fill', '#000').attr('stroke', '#000');

    force.on("tick", function() {

        edges.attr({
            "x1" : function(d) {
                return d.source.x;
            },
            "y1" : function(d) {
                return d.source.y;
            },
            "x2" : function(d) {
                return d.target.x;
            },
            "y2" : function(d) {
                return d.target.y;
            }
        });

        nodes.attr({
            "cx" : function(d) {
                return d.x;
            },
            "cy" : function(d) {
                return d.y;
            }
        });

        nodelabels.attr("x", function(d) {
            return d.x;
        }).attr("y", function(d) {
            return d.y;
        });

        edgepaths.attr('d', function(d) {
            var path = 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y;
            return path
        });

        edgelabels.attr('transform', function(d, i) {
            if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
                bbox = this.getBBox();
                rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
                ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
                return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
            } else {
                return 'rotate(0)';
            }
        });
    });
});
}
```

Comment: look into the enter, exit and update pattern for d3, there's plenty of good blog posts about the topic

Comment: Thanks @Davidlrnt but as I understand it the enter/exit is for dynamically adding and removing data? I'd prefer a complete re-read of json and refresh/redraw of the graph because the json data may be changed on the back-end. I can see the enter() calls but I thought nullifying the nodes object for example would get rid of all the references

Answer (score 0):

Would be easier to help, if there would be link to your code "in action". Are there any errors in console?
Anyway I would suggest you to try to clean your variables also after you get response. I used to have similar problem because, when I re-requested data, previous force.tick() was still running in background even though you set force to null. Therefore try something like this:

```
d3.json("/workflows/graph.json?id=1", function (error, dataset) {

   if (error)
            throw error;

   if (force){ // check if force exists (should exist if you are calling it 2nd time)
        force.stop();
        force = null;

    // You can clean other variables here too, but with issue, which you show, looks more like force problem

    }

    //Here goes rest of your code
}
```

Hopefully it will help.